# Virtual Box not loading after Loading Screen

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, virtualbox, macos-sierra, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to load MacOS Sierra on Oracle VM Virtual box, after selecting the file to be loaded and loading, it initially works for a second and after that its stuck with a black screen.

The Error Log shows no error but the enumeration stops as soon as it loads.

My System Specifications are as below:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- RAM: 8 GB
- Graphics Card: Nil

I will share my log below:

> 00:00:24.613798 Changing the VM state from 'SUSPENDED' to 'RESUMING'
>
> 00:00:24.614520 AIOMgr: Endpoint for file '/home/adminuser16/mac/macOS Sierra Final by Techsviewer/macOS Sierra Final by Techsviewer.vmdk' (flags 000c0723) created successfully
>
> 00:00:24.673768 AIOMgr: Flush failed with VERR_INVALID_PARAMETER, disabling async flushes
>
> 00:00:24.674413 Changing the VM state from 'RESUMING' to 'RUNNING'
>
> 00:00:24.674459 Console: Machine state changed to 'Running'
>
> 00:02:33.602152 GUI: UIMediumEnumerator: Medium-enumeration finished!
>
> 00:02:50.289885 GUI: UIMediumEnumerator: Medium-enumeration finished!
>
> 00:06:10.382706 GUI: UIMediumEnumerator: Medium-enumeration started...
>
> 00:06:10.732756 GUI: UIMediumEnumerator: Medium-enumeration finished!

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There can be many reasons for that, but you should probably first focus on the first message in the log: it seems you are launching a suspended virtual machine. Was is created/suspended on the same machine ? Are you trying to import a suspended machine from another installation of VB ? This might be the cause of your problem. I would suggest to start by:

- trying to start another fresh VM (empty HDD and installation CD loaded in CD reader, or an appliance downloaded from the web
- trying to stop your VM and reboot it.

Comment: I  actually downloaded the mac sierra and is trying to load it via VM, it loads but the issue is after it loads. It loads and the action suspends soon enough.